# Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object. in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym8LR.png) this is my database with three tables

1.users  (user has one account).

2.Account (account has many transactions).
3.Transactions.

---

my Account table

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Account = sequelize.define("Account", {
    UserId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: true,
    }, 
    UUID: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    }, 
    amount: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      defaultValue: 0,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  Account.associate = function(models) {
    Account.hasMany(models.Transaction, {
      foreignKey: 'UserId',
      targetKey: 'UUID'
    });
  };
  
  Account.associate = function (models) {
    Account.belongsTo(models.Users,{
      foreignKey: "UserId",
    })
  }

  return Account;
};
```

---

my transaction table

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Transaction = sequelize.define("Transaction", {
    
    UUID: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    mode: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM("debit", "credit"),
      defaultValue: "debit",
    },
    balance: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    day: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: false,
    },
  });
  // Transaction.associate = function (models) {
  //   Transaction.belongsTo(models.Account);
  // };
  Transaction.associate = function(models) {
    Transaction.belongsTo(models.Account, {
      foreignKey: 'UserId',
    });
  };

  return Transaction;
};
```

---

my route to select accounts associated to transactions

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Account } = require("../models");
const {Transactions} = require("../models")

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await Account.findAll({
      include:[
        {
          modal : Transactions,
        }
      ]
    });
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send({ err: "Error fetching users",error: error });
  }
});
```

i am facing this error

```
Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.
    at Account._conformInclude (S:\test\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:323:11)        
    at S:\test\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:270:61
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Account._conformIncludes (S:\test\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:270:39)       
    at Account._baseMerge (S:\test\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:622:10)
    at Account._defaultsOptions (S:\test\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:656:17)       
    at Account._injectScope (S:\test\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2001:10)
    at Account.findAll (S:\test\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1105:10)
    at S:\test\server\routes\Transactions.js:8:33    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (S:\test\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

---

i want  i have tried to get users and accounts it works but account and their transactions failed please help

this is working

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Account, Users } = require("../models");
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const accounts = await Users.findAll({
      attributes: ["fullName", "status"],
      include: [
        {
          model: Account,
          where: {
            UserId: {
              [Op.not]: null
            }
          }
        },
      ],
    });

    res.json(accounts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({ error: error });
  }
});
```

Thanks you so much

Comment: There's a typo. Use `model : Transactions` instead of `modal : Transactions`

Comment: thanks but which table should i include Account or Transactions

Comment: Transactions, because you want to query Accounts with their associated Transactions